# Change the value of SendBufferSize in apache 2

Tags: php, apache2, buffer

I was wondering how to change the value of the `SendBufferSize` in apache2. I could not find that variable in the apache2.conf file also. I was just trying to follow the steps here http://fplanque.com/dev/linux/why-echo-is-slow-in-php-how-to-make-it-really-fast in order to make my php script faster.

Comment: This could also go in your .htaccess file or your sites conf file under /etc/apache2/sites-available folder.

Comment: Where could i localte that .htaccess file ?.  @Twisty

Comment: This would be in the same location as the website content, Since it's a dot file, it will be invisible. Can run `ls -al` to see it